# Running interactive java code with qsub

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm trying to run my Java code remotely using SSH.  I need to do this with qsub, so I've created a short bash script that compiles my Java files and then runs the main one.

Here's the thing: My code (when run without qsub) prompts the user for a file name and a user name.  When run with qsub, it doesn't do this but the job completes.

How would I (still using qsub) get this interactivity back?  My code will print a bunch of results when run without qsub so I'd like that as well.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with qsub, but does it appear that your code gets input for the file & usernames? qsub may be directing your script's input to /dev/null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qsub` submits your java program to a batch queuing system, and eventually it runs on one of the compute nodes in the cluster - how do you expect to be able to interactively input data in that situation?  there is no tty or screen or keyboard.

You need to modify your program to take command line arguments and give the filename and username on the command line when you use `qsub` to submit the job.